# Rails returns error 500. Log writes full error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, message

Why does rails returns error 500 to the page while in log write NoMethodError?
Can I get the full message to the browser?

My development.rb has the line:
config.consider_all_requests_local = true

In some errors, the full error message is rendering to the browser. In the others I get error 500 to the browser and the full error message to the log.

How can I get always the full error message to the browser?

I'm using rails 3.0.11.

(In development env)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add to  development.rb or production.rb
    config.log_level = :debug